# Nodejs file writing strange behavior and variable value issue

Tags: node.js, file

I have 2 questions about the code below I wrote to save the data om JSON returned by some REST services

### Problem 1

I have a kind of problem before writing to files the data returned by some REST services.
The problem is not calling the rest service and getting the data. But just before it writes to the directory

When I call the function , in the trace there's a error " Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/home/inttyl/data/'"

The files are all correctly saved in the directory
I dont understand why there`s an error.

### Problem 2

The second problem is the output,

I was expecting the whole path+ filename

SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/**file1.js**

and not only the path

SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/

### Thanks a lot for your help

Here the code

```
services.forEach(function(currVal, index, array) {

    fullUrl = url + currVal.path;
    fullPath = dataDirectory + currVal.fileName;

    console.log(" Processing writing to file:: " + fullPath);

    request
        .get(fullUrl)
        .on("error", function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullPath))
        .on("error", function(err) {
            console.log(" ERROR : wirting in file : " + fullPath);
            console.log("        " + err);

        })
        .on("finish", function() {
            console.log("  Successfully write to file:  " +  fullPath);
        });

});
```

Here the traces I got :

```
 Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/file1.js
 Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/file2.js
 Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/file3.js
 Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil4.js
 Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil5.js
 Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/file6.js
 Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/file7.js
 Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js

 ERROR : writing to the file  :/home/inttyl/data/
        Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/home/inttyl/data/'
  SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js
  SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js
  SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js
  SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js
  SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js
  SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js
  SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js
  SUCCES writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/fil8.js
```

### EDIT

**Problem 1** solved, my bad because in the data, there one fileName attritue that is invalid.

For **problem 2**,  I updates the trace and it always print the last filename.  Do you have an idea how to solve it ?  it is a problem with closure but I dont known how to do it .

Comment: The problem is not within the code presented, but the input given by `currVal` seems to be wrong.

Comment: Does the `services` array have a `.` or `..` filename entry in it or an entry with a blank filename? I'd suggest you show a `console.log()` of the services array.

Comment: @Sirko ,    indeed in my data , theres an entry that had  file name is empty !!!

Comment: @jfriend00 ,  thanks ,  my bad, the data is missing a filename !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem 1

Take a look at the last message of your "Processing" log:

*Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/**data/***

It does not contain a file like the others:

*Processing writing to file:: /home/inttyl/data/**file1.js***

So the process is trying to write to a `dir` instead of a `file`, and that is the cause of `Error: EISDIR`

At this function, you probably want to make sure that `currVal.fileName` is valid before the processing.

## Problem 2

Declare your variables with `let` or `const`.

e.g. `const fullPath = dataDirectory + currVal.fileName;`

It was indeed a problem of closure/scope. You weren't declaring your variables, even with `var`, which makes them to be set at the global scope. So, for each step in the loop you were assigning the value to the same variable. "Later", at the "finish" of the first *writefile*, it would be logging the last value assigned to `fullPath`.

By declaring the variable, each loop is now handling its own set of variables.

Tip: go with `'use strict'`. It will force you to declare you variables.

Comment: Indeed the filnename attribut of one entry in my array is not valid

Comment: @inttyl yeah i thought that something like that would be the case.

Comment: thansk,  have an idea for problem 2,   I updated the trace  and it always print the last filename

Comment: @inttyl what is the version of Node.js that you are working with?

Comment: @inttyl declare your variables with `let` or `const`. e.g. `const fullPath = dataDirectory + currVal.fileName;`

Comment: it works,   but I dont understand why. Could you explain.   I thought it was a problem  of closure. [javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)